# How to get variable price via WooCommerce REST API with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, woocommerce

I use ReactJS to build a mobile web app for a WooCommerce shop based on Rest API.  Now the question is how to get the price of variation product when selecting the different attributes.

I made a simple demo to descript my issue. https://mofect.com/test 
In this demo, after all data is loaded, you can see two options and JSON data in Chrome console,  I want to show the final price after set the Size and Color attributes.

I can only get the attributes and variants id from the product Rest API:

```
{
  id: 40
  attributes:[
    {id: 0, name: "Color", position: 1, visible: true, variation: true}
    {id: 0, name: "Size", position: 2, visible: true, variation: true}
  ]
  variations:[106, 107, 108, 109]
}
```

Then, according to the WooCommerce API documentation http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-product-variations, I can get all the variations price by product id:

'products/40/variations/'

```
{
  id: 109
  attributes:[
    {id: 0, name: "Color", option: "White"}
    {id: 0, name: "Size", option: "Large"}
  ],
  price: "40"
}
```

//.... and the other variations arguments

Now the question is how I get variation price from selected attributes?

Any ideas can inspire me would be appreciated!

My source code is available to download here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yikqwdox47dwo6t/woo-test.zip?dl=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to call the products details by the default endpoint of WooCommerce is "/products/41" Where you can get all products details with the variation data.

Variation Data you will get like this:

```
"variations": [
            64,
            57,
            58,
            59
          ]
```

Then you can get the product variation by the variation id like this:

```
/products/41/variations/64
```

Using this you can get all details of the variation along with the variation image, attributes, price, etc.